# Can't find the bin folder of Julia?

Tags: julia, atom-editor

I had installed Julia Programming Language in my Windows 10 Laptop. I want to add this to PATH variable in my system's Environment Variables but I am unable to locate the executable file. Can you please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the current Julia version the path has slightly changed and is:

```
C:\Users\your-user-name\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia\Julia-1.4.2\bin
```

Julia in Windows normally installs itself to the Start Menu. Hence, if you forgot the location of your installation go to the Start menu, type `julia` and launch the Julia REPL command line.

Having the command line running you can ask Julia where it is:

```
julia> println(Sys.BINDIR)
C:\Users\your-user-name\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia\Julia-1.4.2\bin
```

I would advise against creating the `*.bat` file suggested in another answer because when you update Julia in the future (which always means a new directory) you might forget where your `*.bat` file was and commands such as `println(Sys.BINDIR)` will not help (however in Windows there is a good-to-know command `where julia.exe` that shows how your Julia executable will be found in `PATH`).